# Is this de best way to update an entity from DataContext?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, linq-to-sql

I've found that this is the way to update an entity from a DataContext

```
    public bool UpdateLead(Lead lead)
    {

        OrganizationServiceContext context = GetOrgContext();
        Lead leadToTrack = getLead(lead.Id, context);
        leadToTrack.AccountId.Id = lead.AccountId.Id;
        //...
        context.UpdateObject(leadToTrack);

        context.SaveChanges();

        return true;
    }
```

But I have about 200 fields in that entity (thanks to Microsoft Dynamics CRM). Do I have to write 200 lines like `leadToTrack.Field1 = lead.Field1` or is there a more concise way?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) for this - if you have that many properties that all basically have the same name on both sides this should work well for you.

Comment: +1 this is a mapping exercise, @Mathieu also take a look at ValueInjecter it will probably make things easier for you than AutoMapper.

Answer (score 2):

You can attach the entity and change it's object state entry...

```
context.Leads.Attach(lead);

ObjectStateEntry entry = context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(lead);
entry.ChangeState(EntityState.Modified);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with reflection.  Here's a similar method I wrote for that purpose:

```
    public static FMVHistory CloneFMV(FMVHistory F) {
        FMVHistory F_Clone = new FMVHistory();

        Type typeToClone = F.GetType();
        Type[] BadGenericTypes = new Type[] { typeof(EntityCollection<>), typeof(EntityReference<>) };
        Type[] BadTypes = new Type[] { typeof(System.Data.EntityKey) };

        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in typeToClone.GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanWrite)) {
            if (pi.PropertyType.IsGenericType && BadGenericTypes.Contains(pi.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
                || (BadTypes.Contains(pi.PropertyType))
                || (pi.Name.Equals("nameOfYourPrimaryKeyWhichYouDontWantCloned"), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
                continue;

            pi.SetValue(F_Clone, pi.GetValue(F, null), null);
        }
        return F_Clone;
    }
```

Except instead of passing in one object to be cloned, you'd pass in a source object, and a destination object, and copy the values over from one to the other.